# Is it possible to debug react components using break-points(or any other good techniques) in the browsers?

Tags: reactjs

I'm a bit new to react. I'm using React Developer Tools plugin in google chrome for debugging the react components. but we can't set any break-points  and debug the react components(like the way we use breakpoints for debugging Java script code). is there any debugging techniques available for getting more insight into the react components?

Comment: Why don't You use standard js debugger with breakpoints?
http://prntscr.com/fn5wsh

Comment: I know you can get by with the excellent Chrome debugger tools, but I still find them clunky compared to a decent IDE. I personally use WebStorm as I'm familiar with Jetbrains' suite of IDEs/Tools and the debugging in it is outstanding.